# Cannot kill a java process

Tags: linux, process, java, kill

I have a java process that cannot be killed. I have tried every method I know, or that I have found on the internet to no avail. I have tried:

```
killall java
kill -9 <pid>
kill -11 <pid>
kill -6 <pid>
```

No matter what I try, I cannot kill the program. If this helps, it has a dynamic PID, and this has happened before and I somehow killed it last time.

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct PID?

Comment: Are you sure the program is still alive and not a zombie? BTW: There is usually no reason to `kill -9` a process. Sending a `SIGTERM`, then `SIGQUIT` or `SIGINT` should make the program quit. If it doesn't it's buggy.

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's often impossible to kill processes that are currently waiting on I/O.

Comment: Disagree with Marco about the use value of SIGKILL and the assertion that a program that responds to that but not SIGTERM is "buggy". $0.02

Comment: @goldilocks A program cannot respond to SIGKILL. Usually you want to give the program a change to clean up (close files, network connections, etc) and then exit and that's what SIGTERM is for. If you tell a program to terminate and it refuses, it's a bug! SIGINT or SIGQUIT should not be necessary, but some programs respond to the signals and exit immediately. SIGKILL is only useful if you want to *prevent* the program from cleaning up or in the rare case it got stuck in the clean-up code.

Comment: @Marco I am aware of how signal handling works, and the fact that "a program cannot respond to SIGKILL" is the use-value I was referring to.  If SIGTERM does not work, use SIGKILL. The fact that a process hangs in clean-up on an arbitrary SIGTERM may or may not be evidence of a bug in that program -- it may also be due to explicit mis-use, problems with the system (IO), or a problem/bug in a shared component.  Not responding to SIGTERM is not a good sign, but signs like that could be considered *a feature* as opposed to a bug, depending on the context.

Comment: What is the output of `ps l 1234` where 1234 is the process ID?

Comment: I have a Java program which occasionally gets immune to `SIGKILL`. In such cases I send it to background with Ctrl-Z when `kill -9 %1` works.

Answer (score 3):

It's rare but possible for processes to end up in a **D** (uninterrupted sleep) state and they cannot be killed.  You can check with:

```
ps -o cmd,stat -p <pid>
```

If the STAT is D, that's the issue.

If not I suggest you add some more information to your post such as **exactly** what the process is, what it is doing, and why you want to kill it.

Comment: Most of the time this is due to faulty hardware, a kernel bug, or issues with network storage such as NFS.

Comment: Yes -- a failing hard disk would be a possble cause.  If there are bad blocks somewhere the JRE in particular wants access, that would do it.